# Is glDrawElements supposed to be working in Emscripten's current release? (v1.37.1)

Tags: opengl, webgl, emscripten

Is glDrawElements() supposed to be working in Emscripten's current release? (v1.37.1) Because no matter what I do, calling glDrawElements() gives me Error 1282 and of course, nothing is rendered in the browser.

Important: program runs perfectly after compiling with VS for PC, even with the shaders written for WebGL. Everything works as expected, and no errors are produced. But on the web: Error 1282.

Main loop:

```
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

glBindVertexArray(VaoId);

glGetError(); // Clear any previous errors
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
int error = glGetError(); if (error != 0) printf("Error: %i\n", error);

glBindVertexArray(0);

glfwPollEvents();
glfwSwapBuffers(m_Instance);
```

I'm only trying to render a quad as well, 1 VBO in a VAO, indices and positions both stored in one VBO. Indicies first, starting at 0. VertexAttribPointers are set correctly. Shaders compile for the web-browser without errors. Literally the only time glGetError() produces an error-code is straight after the glDrawElements() call.

Is this an emscripten bug, or a WebGL bug?

[EDIT]

Compiling using:

em++ -std=c++11 -s USE_GLFW=3 -s FULL_ES3=1 -s ALLOW_MEMORY_GROWTH=1 --emrun main.cpp -o t.html

Comment: There is a way to get more detailed WebGL error information. (I think) if you use Firefox Nightly, and compile with debug mode in emscripten, that might be it. There are subtle differences between WebGL 2, GLES 3.0 and Open GL 3.x, so it's possible (likely) that it's your error, and not a bug in WebGL or emscripten, but the extra error message will help track it down.

Answer (score 0):

> Is this an emscripten bug, or a WebGL bug?

It's probably a bug in your code.

I find NVIDIA's drivers to be more forgiving than AMD's drivers, leading it to execute code which the latter would violently reject. It may be possible something similar is happening here; your code works fine as a native application, but in a browser environment, the bug becomes a critical issue. This could be explained, for example, by Chrome's use of [ANGLE](http://angleproject.org/), which implements OpenGL with Direct3D (on Windows), which could lead to some differences to your native graphics driver. Of course, this is just speculation, nevertheless, it's unlikely that a function as essential as `glDrawElements` would be broken.

Error code 1282 is `GL_INVALID_OPERATION`, which for `glDrawElements` "is [in this case most likely] generated if a non-zero buffer object name is bound to an enabled array or the element array and the buffer object's data store is currently mapped" ([source](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glDrawElements.xhtml)).

Alternatively, it is possible that your shader might be causing the error, in which case, it would be useful if you shared its source with us.

Comment: Hi, I did an extensive debugging session and turns out there were multiple things in my code that would easily work on PC with no errors or warnings whatsoever, but wouldn't work the same way on the web. After an afternoon's research I've managed to correct around 90% of these mistakes and adjust my code to webgl's expectations. I'm still getting some errors and warnings but finally my 3D world is at least being drawn :)

Comment: Glad to hear it :). Good luck with those 10%.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who might be having issues with the glDrawElements() call specifically on the Web:

My problem turned out to be the fact that I was storing the indices in 1 buffer with all the vertext attributes. This worked fine on PC but for the web, what you need to do is create **2 separate buffers** - 1 for indices, and another 1 for all the positions/uvs/normals etc.. then set the "vertexAttributePointers" appropriately in the vbo. Because in the browser, you can't bind a buffer to an array, and also to another buffer, which is what OpenGL will let you do on the PC, and it will work with no errors/warnings.

Make sure to bind both the VBO and the IBO to the VAO upon initialization. Then, just rebind the VAO, draw, unbind VAO, go render next object - job done.